# how to check if two verticies are connected with an edge in orient DB using java

Tags: orientdb

I am working with orientDB using Java and I need to check if two vertices are connected, I tried to do a workaround be checking out and in edges for vertices and see if the other vertex in there, the solution works fine so far, i have seen that there is a method called "getEdgesBetweenVertexes()" but seems this method not existing in v 2.2 anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method called `getEdges()`

Example:

```
OrientVertex v1=graph.getVertex("#21:0");
OrientVertex v2=graph.getVertex("#26:1");

if(v2!=null){
    Iterable<Edge> result=v1.getEdges(v2, Direction.BOTH, "E");
    boolean connected=false;
    for(Edge e:result){
        connected=true;
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(connected);
}
else{
    System.out.println(false);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is great